# IntelliSense - 'this' not inherit objects on Javascript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I followed this tutorial [Type Vue without TypeScript](https://blog.usejournal.com/type-vue-without-typescript-b2b49210f0b) and I notice this image the IntelliSense should automatically recognize the content inside 'data'

[image]

But trying it by myself, on both VS 2019 and VS Code the result is

[image]

[image]

I expected 'name' to be recognized as a string. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I'm almost sure that, for that, you need the [Vetur extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) installed in your VS Code

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work with the Vetur extension either.